# Display a list of users from a REST API and filter with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new here and also new to react js and I'm having trouble solving 1 exercise that asks to display a list of users coming from a REST API and then to be able to filter it.

I have managed to show it but I don't know how to do the filter.

EDIT:

Well Thanx I manage to use filters as you say :D.

But now I want the user to be able to select which columns are shown and which are not.

For this I have created a select from which I plan to remove the filter but I don't really know how to proceed :/

[image: my app]

This is how I'm doing the filter, using a text input.

```
//Query
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const search = (data) => {
    return data.filter(
      item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(query));
  }
```

the select

```
<select className='select' onChange={changeFilter}>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="username">Username</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
      </select>
```

So basically I pretend to change the
"name" here: item.**name**.toLowerCase().includes(query));
for filter and if **All** is selected its shows all.

Any help with this?

Code from the fetch:

```
// users from API.
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);






  // async function
  const fetchData = async () => {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setUsers(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR:" + error);
      })
  }
```

**I modified the way I call the component in App.js**

```
  <div className="App">
      <h1>PRUEBA DE NIVEL</h1>

      <select className='select' onChange={changeSelectedFilter}>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="username">Username</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text"
        placeholder='Search...'
        className='search'
        onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
      />
      <UserTable data={search(users)} filter={selectedFilter} />

    </div>
```

Comment: If the data is fetched fine, when mapping `UsersList`, you could add a filter in the chain as `users.filter().map()`. But how would you like to filter it?

Comment: ^ For example: do you want a drop-down list that filters the data by a one particular property type? When you figure that out you should have that component update a separate state, and then use that in the condition of `filter` to produce a new array of data which can be rendered.

Comment: Hi Adrián Ruiz! Your last edit is asking for help with a new concern. Please consider accepting the answer that helped you with the initial problem and ask a new question for the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like this:

```js
const isUserEligible = (user) => {
  if(/* the condition that the user must have */) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```js
users.filter((user) => isUserEligible(user)).map((user) => (
  <UsersList
    key={user.id}
    name={user.name}
    username={user.username}
    email={user.email}
    phone={user.phone}
  />
))
```

**Update:**

I didn't understand your question completely.
But if you want to show only the selected column in the select box, you can define a state for your select like this:

```js
const [selectedColumn, setSelectedColumn] = useState("");
const changeSelectedColumn = (event) => {
  setSelectedColumn(event.target.value);
}
```

```html
<select className='select' onChange={changeSelectedColumn}>
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="username">Username</option>
  <option value="email">Email</option>
  <option value="phone">Phone</option>
</select>
```

And then you can pass the selectedColumn to your UsersList component like this:

```js
users.map((user) => (
  <UsersList
    key={user.id}
    name={user.name}
    username={user.username}
    email={user.email}
    phone={user.phone}
    selectedColumn={selectedColumn}
  />
))
```

And finally in your UsersList component, show only the selected column by 'if, else' base on the value of the selectedColumn or show all if the selectedColumn value is "". (Means that the user selected All columns).

If you also want to filter by the query, you can use the filter method again as I said before.

Comment: I'm trying what you suggested but I'm having a problem.
When I try to pass multiple props to my UserList component one of them is always undefined, I think Im making some kind of mistake.

**App.js**
 `<UserList data={search(users)} colum={selectedColum} />`

**UserList component**

``export const UserLable = ({ data }, colum) => {
...
``

Colum is a string as you say I get that by changeSelectedColum but now Idk how to pass that to my component.

Comment: There is a problem with your UsersList component definition.
It should be like this:
`export const UsersList = ({data, column}) => {...};`
And then get the value of the column to conditionally render the columns.
And finally use it like this:
`<UsersList data={search(users)} column={selectedColumn} />`

Comment: Also you can use this definition:
`export const UsersList = (props) => {...};`
And get the value of the column prop with `props.column`.
`Be aware that you should use 1 single object as your props in component. So ({data}, column) is wrong.`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a state called `filterInput` for example and an `input`, and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Like so:

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [filterInput, setFilterInput] = useState("");
```

```js
<div>
  <input type="text" value={filterInput} onChange={() => setFilterInput(e.target.value)} />
  {users
    .filter((user) => user.name.includes(filterInput) || user.username.includes(filterInput))
    .map((user) => (
      <UsersList
        key={user.id}
        name={user.name}
        username={user.username}
        email={user.email}
        phone={user.phone}
      />
    ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[.filter MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
users.filter(user => user.name.startsWith('R')).map((user) => (
    <UsersList
      key={user.id}
      name={user.name}
      username={user.username}
      email={user.email}
      phone={user.phone}
    />
  ));
```